# Use command grep and locate

Tags: command-line, grep, pipe, xargs, locale

How I can make the grep command locate certain words in the files specified by the routes found by the locate command?

```
locate my.cnf | grep user
```

(I want that grep command search the word "user" on the files found for locate command)

Comment: You might have a read through [When is xargs needed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24954) for some explanations of what's going on here with arguments vs. pipes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your search results are sure to return paths with no spaces, you could use `xargs` like this:

```
locate my.cnf | xargs grep user
```

However you should get in the habit of protecting yourself to handle the case where a path or filename might contain a space by telling `xargs` to use `null` as a separator and telling `locate` (or whatever program you are using to return strings) to also send that as the separator like this:

```
locate -0 my.cnf | xargs -0 grep user
```

This would work even if your path included blanks like `/name with space/my.cnf`.

Comment: Slightly more idiomatic than mine.

Comment: You might want `locate my.cnf | xargs grep -H user` so that the output lines report which file(s) the match was found in.

Comment: i'd use `locate -0 my.cnf | xargs -0 -r grep user` in case any filenames had spaces etc in them.  Note that not all versions of `locate` support the `-0` or `--null` option for null-terminated output.  `mlocate` does.  IIRC, GNU locate does too.

Comment: @vitiv: It's not slightly more idomatic, yours just doesn't work. Try it. Even when you fix it, then you have to add even more fixes to handle paths with spaces. By the time it actually works, yours will be the more idomatic, although in a more complex setup it could also be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
typeset what1=$1
typeset what2=$2
[ "$#" -eq 2 ] || { echo "Two arguments expected"; exit 1; }
locate ${what1} | while read file; do
    grep ${what2} ${file} /dev/null
    done
```

This searches the files matching the `locate` argument (`what1`) for a string that matches `what2`.  The `dev/null` argument forces `grep` to report the file name of a match.

Comment: Interesting hack by adding `/dev/null`, although you can also echo the file name yourself.

Comment: @Caleb : Yes I could have added an `echo ${file}` but I dislike having to spawn yet another process just for that purpose.

Comment: There is typically a shell builtin for `echo` so it does not spawn a process anyway.

Comment: @Caleb : Ah, yes, I forgot that.  Thanks!

Comment: If you were worried about that, doesn't adding `/dev/null` force grep to open a file pointer to it for ever iteration over the loop? That would cost more than an echo I'd think.

Comment: Actually the real problem is the gymnastics of getting it to do the echo before the match only if there is a match. It can be done but it's kind of ugly. Usually I don't want the matches at all however so it's `grep -q "#what2" && [other action]`. As I said, that is an interesting hack however and I'll remember it, may come in handy although I tend to dislike things that their function isn't readily apparent to somebody reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

One-liner:

`for file in $(locate my.cnf) ; do grep -r user "$file" ; done`

If you want to search pattern in files under the directory name you got from locate then `-r` will take care of it otherwise remove `-r`.