# Pipe the result of a cut command to curl

Tags: grep, curl, cut

I have a csv file that contains 3 fields per line.

`firstname,lastname,url`

I'm trying to access the url via the following pipeline:

`grep theName file.csv | cut -d, -f 3`

then I want to add another pipe and use the results of the cut command in a curl command like so:

`grep theName file.csv | cut -d, -f 3 | curl > result.txt`

problem is, when i do the above, the curl command throws an error, i assume because curl doesn't have an argument?

how can I use the result of cut to curl the resulting url? Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: By the way, this assumes your CSV fields have no internal commas. Be careful.

Comment: Be aware that URLs may contain commas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Leverage command substitution, `$()`:

```
curl "$(grep ... | cut -d, -f 3)"
```

Here `$()` will be substituted by the STDOUT of the command inside `$()` i.e. `grep ... | cut -d, -f 3`, as this is done by the shell first so the `curl` command would be finally:

```
curl <the_url>
```

Comment: Duh. i should have known that and it didn't even occur to me. Well done. this works perfectly. It won't let me mark this correct yet. I'll try to remember and come back to mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @wdowling, should be long enough now.

Comment: I know that few users use anything other than `bash` these days, but this is a `bash`ism. The portable answer is `curl \`grep ... | cut -d, -f 3\`` - although I much prefer the `xargs` solution, it's more flexible in general.

Comment: @reinierpost No, `$()` is defined by POSIX.

Comment: OK, thanks, it's a POSIXism then. I'm not sure how many non-POSIX-compliant `sh`s are still out there. I just checked and `dash` and `ash` both support it.

Answer (score 11):

Another solution without substitution:

```
grep theName | cut -d, -f 3 | xargs curl > result.txt
```

Comment: This answer works just as well as the other answer and i like that the flow doesn't change. My only question is, is xargs supported cross platform? I routinely go back and forth between my linux box and a mac, so I always want to make sure i don't get in the habit of doing something that I can't do on one machine. Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: utfg: https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html

Comment: @wdowling, it's portable but still a bad habit to get into.  See the last paragraph of [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24956/135943).

Comment: xargs is very widely available.

Comment: `xargs` is better than command substitution in case your input has funny characters - it has options to deal with them, e.g. I like to provide `-d'\n'`.

Comment: @reinierpost URLs don't have funny characters to begin with.

Comment: I'm just commenting on why `xargs` may be a *good* habit to get into. For this particular case it doesn't seem to make much of a difference (unless the input is extremely long, command substitution might have a limit there).