# Could you explain why this command(pgrep -d ',' -f cmdStr | top -c -p) doesn't work ?

Tags: pipe

While looking for how to filter command in `top` console, I found the answer.

```
top -c -p $(pgrep -d',' -f string_to_match_in_cmd_line)
```

It works perfectly.

I think It is the same as the command `pgrep -d ',' -f cmdStr | top -c -p` because they will work to feed the output of `pgrep` to input of `top` at least I think.

However, as you expect it returns an error `top: -p requires argument`

What is different between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are not the same. Consider the `echo` command. Do you expect

```
echo hello asleea
```

and

```
printf "asleaa\n" | echo hello
```

to produce the same thing? In the `top ... $(...)` case the shell first runs the stuff inside the `$(...)`, and places the output in the list of arguments for when it runs `top`.

Of course `top` **could** be written to read additional values from stdin if you gave it a flag which required an argument but didn't give it one, but that is not how it is implemented.

Comment: I have to look for it(http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24956/125570)  to understand this answer.

Comment: @asleea I'm sorry. What could I have written which would have made it clearer?