# Regex Pattern and Replace line with substitution

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl, xargs

For a migration process, I need to do some replacement in my bash script.

So in my .txt files, I have these references for example:

```
[[File:My Image.png|400px|thumb|center|My Image]]
[[File:My Image.png|400px|thumb|center]]
[[File:My Image.png|400px|thumb]]
[[File:My Image.png|400px]]
[[File:My Image.png]]
```

What I need to do is to replace all these occurrences with this line (only - so no more size, description, or other informations):

```
[[File:My Image.png]]
```

So, I tried to do a is to build a PCRE regex to extract all images names with:

```
/File:(.*\..{3})/g
```

I've built this final command to find all occurrences in my .txt files and extract image name with my regex:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | xargs perl -i -p -e 's/File:(.*\..{3})/$1/g'
```

But, I've encountered some problems as:

- An error:

> xargs: unterminated quote

- And finally I don't know how to use extracted image name to replace all occurrences (complete lines)

PS: I'm on MacOS system and use bash v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec perl -i -pe 's/File:[^|]+\K\|[^]]+//g' {} \;
```

- `File:[^|]+` match `File:` followed by non `|` characters
- `\K` so that we don't have to capture the preceding string and put it back in replacement section
- `\|[^]]+` match `|` followed by non `]` characters to be deleted
- Can also use `sed -i '' 's/\(File:[^|]*\)|[^]]*/\1/g'`instead of `perl`

Further reading:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice) - it has lot of detail on using `find` command including the use of `-exec` option..
- [When is xargs needed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/when-is-xargs-needed)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help and your very great explanation, amazing, it' working great as expected and it's very simple. Nice to see some further reading also, I will take a look as soon as possible ;) Have a nice day

Comment: That regex will also match for example `File:x|y` (without the preceding `[[`).

Comment: @haukex true, and it is a good point :) I was modifying OP's attempt which didn't include the starting `[[` or ending `]]`, so probably they do not make a difference for given input...

Answer (score 1):

I've written [a new regex](https://regex101.com/r/RuIT0S/1) which matches the whole `[[...]]`, and replaces it by only the things you want to keep. It assumes that the filenames don't contain pipe `|` characters or the terminator `]]`. I can't reproduce your issue with `xargs`, but I replaced it by `find`'s  `-exec` option anyway; the following works for me on Linux.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec perl -i -pe 's/(\[\[File:[^|]*).*?(\]\])/$1$2/g' '{}' +
```